# How to make a text field with round corners in tornado fx? (Kotlin)

Tags: css, kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I wanna make a custom style for a text field. Firs custom property I would like to create round corners. I found here a solution but it's quite tricky for me -> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617760/how-to-set-rounded-corners-to-textarea-in-javafx.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617760/how-to-set-rounded-corners-to-textarea-in-javafx) I'm a beginner when you talk about tornado fx
How to make round corners for a text field in tornado fx with Kotlin, if you know an idea with type-safe DSL method.

Answer (score 0):

For a textfield its quiet simple:

```
textfield("Sometext") {
  style {
    borderRadius += box(40.0.px)
  }
}
```

Here I used inline style (just for this particular element). It's better to define it inside your Styles.kt in general.

Comment: This type of answer I  looking for. Working great!