# How can I use round edges on a scrollpane?

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

I am trying to have round edges, so I tried to look around and found these answers:

https://www.reddit.com/r/JavaFX/comments/tlnhfl/rounded_edges_for_textarea_within_a_scrollpane/

[JavaFX ScrollPane border and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540137/javafx-scrollpane-border-and-background)

[How to set rounded corners to TextArea in JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617760/how-to-set-rounded-corners-to-textarea-in-javafx)

but for some reason non of them are actually working for me.

Here is the fxml file that I am using:

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>

<VBox id="collection" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="200.0" stylesheets="@/client/stylesheets/Global.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.14-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="client.scenes.CollectionOverviewCtrl">

    <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="5">
        <Label id="collection_name" text="Collection name" />
        <Button styleClass="imageButton" id="delete_button" mnemonicParsing="false" text="X"/>
    </HBox>

    <ScrollPane id="containerContainer" fitToHeight="true" prefWidth="200" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <VBox id="container" fx:id="container"/>
    </ScrollPane>

    <Button styleClass="imageButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Add Card" />
</VBox>
```

And this is the css file that I am using:

```css
#collection{
    -fx-background-color: #6096B4;
    -fx-spacing: 25;
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-padding: 5 5 5 5;
}

#collection_name{
    -fx-font-size: 16px;
}

#delete_button{
    -fx-font-size: 10px;
    -fx-background-color: #FF0000;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

#containerContainer{
    -fx-border-radius: 50 50 50 50;
    -fx-border-color: #1526b0;
    -fx-background-color: #0b9c12;
    -fx-background-radius: 50 50 50 50;
}

#container{
    -fx-background-color: #9c0b0b;
    -fx-background-radius: 50 50 50 50;
}
```

And here is what I am getting as a result:

[image]

You can see that it did give it round edges, but no matter what I do, I can't get rid of the white rectangle that is blocking them.
What do I need to change for it to work?

Comment: The structure of a ScrollPane’s descendant nodes is documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#scrollpane).  As you seem to have discovered, you need to style the viewport, not the ScrollPane itself.

Comment: Since your answer is essentially, "This other Q&A provided all the answers I needed", I've closed this question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

[over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952531/scrollpanes-in-javafx-8-always-have-gray-background) I found out that you can use the `>` symbol in css, and that is what saved me, since that let me access the viewport.